# Rendering a form in a different view directory gives error NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails v 7.0.3

I have this table with one variable, name, in it.

The **_form** code, from scaffold generation:

```
<%= form_with(model: course) do |form| %>
  <% if course.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this course from being saved:</h2>
 
      <ul>
        <% course.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.text_field :name, class:"form-control", placeholder:"name" %>
  </div>

<br>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the **courses_controller.rb** file:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
 
  # GET /courses or /courses.json
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  # GET /courses/1 or /courses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /courses/new
  def new
    @course = Course.new
  end

  # GET /courses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /courses or /courses.json
  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to course_url(@course), notice: "Course was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /courses/1 or /courses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.update(course_params)
        format.html { redirect_to course_url(@course), notice: "Course was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /courses/1 or /courses/1.json
  def destroy
    @course.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to courses_url, notice: "Course was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def course_params
      params.fetch(:course, {})
    end
end
```

The snippet of code from my **userHome** file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Make a new course</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Add a course
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Make a new course</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Make a new course</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <%= render "courses/form" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ive also tried render "courses/new" to load the new page from the scaffold into the modal instead, but that doesnt work either.

in **routes.rb** I have

`resources :courses`

Is there anything i'm missing, or another way I can spawn a modal that allows me to input values to save into a database?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think of partials as functions and locals as the parameters that the function takes.

Your partial expects a `course` local to be passed and you're not passing anything. To pass locals [use the locals option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables):

```
<%= render "courses/form", locals: { course: Course.new } %>
```